# R Code for transforming integers to date

Tags: r

I have data set name SE. The column YE contains years as 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, and 2016. When i use code 
<-str(SE$YE) 
it returns as integer. 
How can i change these integers to date format in R

Answer (score 2):

A date in R needs to have a month and day component in addition to a year.  That being said, one option here would be to arbitrarily set each year to be January 1:

```
years <- c(2009, 2010, 2011)
date_str <- paste0(years, '-01-01')
dates <- as.Date(date_str, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

If you need to work with the particular year, you can access it using `format`:

```
new_years <- format(dates, '%Y')
new_years
[1] "2009" "2010" "2011"
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Sir, I have 288 observations. it includes annual values for listed firms from 2008 to 2016. How to change the whole set of 288 observations to date format

Comment: do i have to use loops for this purpose?

Comment: `as.Date` and `format` are vectorized, There is no reason for using `sapply` here.

Comment: @Roland Am I the only one who finds it painful working with base R's date API?

Comment: No, you are not. No, I don't understand why people find vectorization so difficult. For anyone with good algebra education this should be a rather natural way of doing this.

Comment: And R's date API is nothing really special. But you are welcome to use package `anytime`.

Comment: @Roland When I was testing my code it seemed vectorization was not working, hence I fell back to `sapply`.  Hard to do anything on a cell phone.

Comment: I agree with regard to mobile phones. But I avoid writing answers using mine anyway. Still haven't figured out how to write a `\`` with it.

Answer (score 1):

@Saud, following up on @Tim's answer:

you can assign the values of a data frame column simply by doing:

```
SE$year_as_date <-  as.Date(paste(SE$YE, '-01-01', sep=''), "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

This combines the two lines of code posted into one and adds the result as a new column.

Comment: Ok, Thanks sir for ur cooperation